# Windows 10 Storage Spaces - Can't Access Drives

Tags: hard-drive, storage-spaces, refs

This is a difficult issue to Google.

I recently set up a Storage Space (3x 4TB) in Windows 10 and it worked as expected. No parity (Simple) as it’s only for backups.

I then added another independent drive (1x 4TB) to the PC and in the process of trying to get Windows to recognise it I probably booted up with only 2/3 of my pool drives connected.

Even with all three now connected; I now have no visible pool shown in Storage Spaces. This is fine - I'm happy to start again as it's only for backups - but the issue is Windows won't recognise any of the three drives (the new, non-pool drive is recognised) so I can’t format them and start again.

I can see all three drives in the BIOS, but not in Windows - Disk Management, Powershell ‘get-physicaldisk’, DiskPart ‘list disk’ or ‘list volume’. Windows just won’t see the disks so I can’t start again.

I’ve tried plugging one of the pool drives in to a SATA/power connecter that I know is working, but Windows still won’t see the drive.

I understand that Server Manager in Windows Server may be able to see the pool drives and format them, but I don't have access to that.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting the drives one by one and see what is does, maybe it's a problem with the SATA controller on your motherboard.